# Get a row for each year using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

| product_id | period_start | period_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 |
| 2 | 2018-12-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 2019-12-01 | 2020-01-31 |

I want:

| product_id | year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 |
| 2 | 2018 |
| 2 | 2019 |
| 2 | 2020 |
| 3 | 2019 |
| 3 | 2020 |

How can I get one row for each product_id and year combination in SQL?

Comment: You don't want all product/year combinations. You only want the years related to a product. For this you need a recursive query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want all product/year combinations. You only want the years related to a product. For this you need a recursive query.

```
with recursive cte (product_id, year, last_year) as
(
  select product_id, year(period_start), year(period_end) from  products
  union all
  select product_id, year + 1, last_year from cte where year < last_year
)
select product_id, year
from cte
order by product_id, year;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f3bb10734e2aacf99eabc7730e412eb